# google storage python API - uploading an StringIO object

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, stringio

I succeeded in uplaoding a file to the google storage, but I would like to skip the creation of a file and use **StringIO** instead and create the file on the google storage directly.

Since I'm new to python, I just tried to use the standard method that I used for uploading the created file:

```
def cloud_upload(self, buffer, bucket, filename):
    buffer.seek(0)
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket)
    blob = bucket.blob(filename)
    blob.upload_from_filename(buffer)
```

But I get the error:

**TypeError: expected string or buffer**

But since I gave it the StringIO object, I don't know why this isn't working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hope this is still relevant. But you can try using blob.upload_from_string method

```
def cloud_upload(self, buffer, bucket, filename):
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket)
    blob = bucket.blob(filename)
    blob.upload_from_string(buffer.getvalue(),content_type='text/csv')
```

Do take note to modify the content_type parameter if you want to save the file as other file types. I placed 'text/csv' as an example. The default value is 'text/plain'.

Comment: Though this ans is correct, but once take a look in source code, `upload_from_string` simply convert string into `ByteIO` for `upload_from_filename` to upload.

Answer (score 0):

Cause you are uploading from **filename**. But should upload from file object rather. Should be:

```
blob.upload_from_file(buffer)
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure how are you invoking the `cloud_upload` function but you can simply use the `upload_from_filename` function to satisfy your need.

```
def upload_blob(self, bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)

    print('File {} uploaded to {}.'.format(
        source_file_name,
        destination_blob_name))
```

Comment: well, I tried that, but I get TypeError: expected string or buffer...when I try to use buffer(StringIO object) instead of a file...

Comment: Can you try with `blob.upload_from_filename(filename='/local/path.txt')` ?

Comment: yes I did something like that, but I wanted to upload the StringIO object directly - without making a file first and then uploading that!